# I need to round a number's decimal place to a n-number

Tags: java

I need to divide a with b and round that number to a n number of decimals.
example : a = 2 b = 52 n = 5 , Solution = 0.03846.
I can only use intigers!!

I've been working with decimalformat but I don't know how to make the format custom.

```
DecimalFormat nstevilo = new DecimalFormat("#.###");//I need to change ### to a n-number.
    if(x<y) {
    double a = x/y;
    System.out.print(nstevilo.format(a));
    }
```

This only outputs #.### because of the format i need to make it #.######- n times of decimal.

Comment: I've seen the post it's not the same matter.

Comment: where is the problem? building the format string?

Comment: try `new DecimalFormat("#."+ "#".repeat(n))` (Java 9)

Comment: "string as of instruction"? what's that? you are *already* using string as input to the formatter

Comment: @SharonBenAsher i get the error "The method repeat(string) is undefined for the type string.

Comment: I've found a solution, thanks for help

Comment: Hello Libraa. Please do not edit your title, and add SOLVED to it. Instead, either accept the answer that helped you out the most by checking the checkmark next to that answer. Or, add an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
private static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00000");

public static void main(String[] args)
{
        double d = 2 / (double) 52;
        System.out.println(df.format(d));

}
```

Also, if the number of deciamls is dynamic, you can use:

```
private static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();

public static void main(String[] args)
{
            df.setMaximumFractionDigits(5);
            double d = 2 / (double) 52;
            System.out.println(df.format(d));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the second options work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setMaximumFractionDigits(int)` to set that

Example

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
double d = 13/7.0;
System.out.println(d); // 1.8571428571428572
System.out.println(df.format(d)); //1.857
df.setMaximunFractionDigits(4);
System.out.println(df.format(d)); //1.8571
```

Comment: Tried, ends up always outputting the same number of digits even if i change the 4 to 10

Comment: It works on my end. Can you paste your test code where output is same?

Comment: It's okay i figured it out, sorry

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way:

```
int d = x / y; 
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) { 
            System.out.print(d); 
            x = x - (y * d); 
            if (x == 0) 
                break; 
            x = x * 10; 
            d = x / y; 
            if (i == 0) 
                System.out.print("."); 
        }
```

[Details here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-compute-division-upto-n-decimal-places/)

P.S: Make sure to handle for negative inputs

Comment: Does not work outputs 0.0.0.2.3 etc.

Comment: @Libraa, I have updated, please check that.